# Rename tag [xdp]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

Please consider renaming the tag [xdp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xdp). One possibility would be `xdp-pdf`.

This tag has been used for a long time to designate a format related to PDF and XML. From the tag info:

> XML Data Package (XDP), is an XML 1.0 compliant format for packaging PDF content within an XML structure.

But the activity is low. Over the last years, it has been leading to a lot of confusion for users asking questions related to eBPF on Linux, where “XDP” designates a driver-level hook for processing network packets.

eBPF-related XDP has a dedicated tag, [xdp-bpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xdp-bpf), but most users do not care to read the descriptions, and I end up re-tagging a fair half of the questions on the topic. Of  the two tags, `xdp-bpf` has more activity: 66 questions since the end of 2019, while `xdp` was used for... 2 new questions in the same interval.

Renaming [xdp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xdp) as something that evokes PDF or XML, such as maybe `xdp-pdf` or `xdp-xml-pdf` (to avoid confusion between `-bpf` and `-pdf` when reading fast), would likely clear up much of the confusion.

Comment: what about `xml-xdp`?  It follows the general->specific ordering and should deconflict with the bpf usage

Comment: @Gus The `x` in `-xdp` already stands for `XML` so I held off, but this is surely not an issue and `xml-xdp` also sounds good to me.

Comment: What about xml-data-package?

Comment: @Braiam I guess if we add “XDP” in the description of the tag it would show up in suggestions when users are typing the acronym? If so, sounds good to me as well.

Comment: I thought you meant the [`xkcd`](https://xkcd.com/) tag.

Comment: I went with [xdp-pdf] since that was in the excerpt